# How to return all Array value from other class

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

How to return all Array value if it created and initial in separate class of type NSMutableArray.

This is my simple code.

In FirstClassViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyArrayClass *thisArray = [[MyArrayClass alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"%@",thisArray.getArray);

}
```

In MyArrayClass.h

```
@interface MyArrayClass : NSMutableArray{

    NSMutableArray *courseArray;

}

-(NSString*)getArray;
-(void) setArray;
@end
```

In MyArrayClass.m

```
-(NSString*) getArray{

    return courseArray;   
}

-(void) setArray{

    courseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // AR111:    
    [courseArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"AR111",@"courseCode",
                            @"Arabic Communication Skills (I)",@"courseName",
                            @"3",@"creditHours",

                            nil]];

    // AR112:    
    [courseArray addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"AR112",@"courseCode",
                            @"Arabic Communication Skills (II)",@"courseName",
                            @"3",@"creditHours",

                            nil]];
}
```

I have this output message:

2012-07-19 10:36:18.344 test[622:f803] (null)

Comment: You didn't write an initializer (e.g. `- (id) init { ... }`) and you don't seem to call `setArray:` anywhere...so is the array field ever allocated?  Also try changing `- getArray {...` to `- (NSArray*) getArray {`...the lack of return type might be causing some weird behavior.

Comment: do you mean this `MyArrayClass *thisArray = [[MyArrayClass alloc]init];`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your -(NSString *)getArray method is returning an NSMutableArray.... to convert that NSMutableArray to a single string, you might want to check out componentsJoinedByString: in the Apple Docs(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: I think there are many mistakes in this code. Can any one correct it to get idea?